# I need to make sure that I did my coding right for these problem okay

Tags: sqlplus

These are the question to the problem

Set echo on
2.  SET SERVEROUT ON
3.  Set up a spool file to receive your output for submission.  I would suggest c:\CS4210\wa5spool.txt .
4.  DECLARE a record variable (Emp_rec) using %ROWTYPE
5.  In the BEGIN block add a select statement to read a record into the declared variable from HR.EMPLOYEES 
6.  Add If Statement to print record
7.  Add DBMS_OUTPUT lines to print EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, and SALARY for the selected record
8.  Use TO_CHAR to format the salary as $999,999 
9.  Add a EXCEPTION block to report when no data is found 
10. Compile and run the procedure. 
11. Close the spool file

CLARIFICATION: For this assignment, you can use your IF statement to do whatever you want. You can use it to determine the Department, like we did in the past with a CASE, or you can do it to print a message if they make over a certain amount of money, or maybe they are due a raise if they were hired before a certain date. Use your imagination.

```
:
set echo on
set SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
Emp_rec employee%rowtype;
BEGIN
SELECT * into emp_rec FROM HR.EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 5;  
IF Emp_rec.EMPLOYEE_ID = 5 THEN
dbms_output.put_line('Employee ID : ' || Emp_rec.EMPLOYEE_ID);
dbms_output.put_line('First Name : ' || Emp_rec.FIRST_NAME);
dbms_output.put_line('Last Name : ' || Emp_rec.LAST_NAME);
dbms_output.put_line('Salary: ' || TO_CHAR(Emp_rec.salary,'$99,990.99'));
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
INSERT INTO errors VALUES ('No record found in the table ' );
END;
spool off
```

Comment: Does it do what you expect it to do? Do you have any specific problem?

Comment: ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PLS-00201: identifier 'EMPLOYEE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 15:

Comment: ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PLS-00201: identifier 'EMPLOYEE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 15:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
malformed
ORA-06550: line 4, column 23:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 5, column 4:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
malformed
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:

Comment: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 13, column 13:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 13, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Answer (score 0):

As your table seems to be `HR.EMPLOYEES`, your declaration of a rowtype should be `HR.EMPLOYEES%rowtype`.

Comment: You can use it to determine the Department they work for, like we did in the past with a CASE.
You can use it to print a message if they make over a certain amount of money.
Maybe they are due a raise if they were hired before a certain date.

Comment: I don't understand. You copied your assignment. Do you have a question?